# How to answer console output questions in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I have to run one .jar file through bash script.

/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -jar reindexer.jar  "url as parameter"

so script is as follows

```
while read line

do

/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -jar reindexer.jar $line

done < parameter.txt
```

However jar file has coding that it asks question while executing as follows

Do you want to continue?(yes/no)

So how can I answer this question through bash script only.

Comment: `echo y | java -jar reindexer.jar $line`, or `yes | java ...`. If you need more complex interactions, you may need an `expect` script, but that takes you out of your bash only requirement.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you want to give the same answer to all questions you can use the `yes` program:

```
# This answers all questions with 'yes'
yes | /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -jar reindexer.jar "$line"

# This answers all questions with 'no'
yes no | /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -jar reindexer.jar "$line"
```

If you are about to mix `yes` and `no` answers, you can use a here document piped to stdin, like this:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java -jar reindexer.jar "$line" <<EOF
yes
yes
no
yes
EOF
```